# Migrate spring-boot app from 2.3.5 to 2.4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I migrated a spring-boot app from 2.3.5 to 2.4.0 and deployed on tomcat.

The app failed to start-up on :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at **org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:136)**
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemFactory.lambda$fromSpringFactories$0(LoggingSystemFactory.java:44)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.getLoggingSystem(DelegatingLoggingSystemFactory.java:41)
```

I checked https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-23,  but found nothing obvious.

Anyone encountered similar issues and resolved them?

Fixed in 2.4.1

Thanks

Comment: maybe consider to create a bug issue on github about it. It looks logging related, so maybe include your logging configuration.

Comment: thanks, issue fixed in 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

It is due to a bug that is fixed in this commit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/a0544e78ea2b4736122ff0dffaf6fe0c729b32a1#diff-5cfb6e321ece4799e72ea0af1a677eb04698e85458408dfd21e1b8ca2d41b5b0

The fix is available in Spring 5.3.2 and I have confirmed that it works when using that version.

If you are using Maven you can import https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.3.2 above the spring-boot-dependencies BOM in your `<dependencyManagement>`-section.